# Compatibilidad entre MySQLDriverCS y libmysql.dll

Tags: c#, mysql, genexus

Hace tiempo tengo problemas aleatorios con la conexión entre mi aplicación generada con [genexus](/questions/tagged/genexus) y [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

Actualmente utilizo:

- MySQL 5.6.19a
- MySQLDriverCS 3.0.1735.36021
- libmySQL.dll (obtenida de MySQLDriverCS\dll )

Como comentarios, obtuve la `libmySQL` desde la instalación de `MySQLDriverCS` según el artículo: [http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?MySQL+driver+for+.NET+installation,](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?MySQL%20driver%20for%20.NET%20installation,)

Necesitaría que me digan donde puedo descargar el archivo `libmysql.dll` que funciona correctamente con la versión de `MySQLDriverCS` que viene en GxEv3 U6 de Genexus/CSharp.

Algunos errores que obtengo de forma aleatoria:

```
/* el más común */
GxCommand - Return GxCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Error
MySQLDriverCS.MySQLException (0x80004005): MySQLDriverCS Exception: MySQLDriverCS Error: wrong query.
   at MySQLDriverCS.PreparedStatement.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at MySQLDriverCS.MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

/* Segundo más común */
GxCommand - Return GxCommand.ExecuteReader Error
MySQLDriverCS.MySQLException (0x80004005): MySQLDriverCS Exception: MySQLDriverCS Error: Row retrieval was canceled by mysql_stmt_close() call
   at MySQLDriverCS.MySQLCursorDataReader.Read()
   at GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand.ExecStmtFetch1()
   at GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand.ExecuteReader()

/* otro */
    MySQLDriverCS.MySQLException (0x80004005): MySQLDriverCS Exception: MySQLDriverCS Error: MySQL server has gone away
       at MySQLDriverCS.DirectStatement.ExecuteReader(Boolean CloseConnection)
       at MySQLDriverCS.MySQLCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean CloseConnection)
       at MySQLDriverCS.MySQLCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand.ExecStmtFetch1()
       at GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand.ExecuteReader()


/* otro */
    System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
       at MySQLDriverCS.CPrototypes.mysql_stmt_fetch(IntPtr stmt)
       at MySQLDriverCS.MySQLCursorDataReader.Read()
       at GeneXus.Data.GxDataReader.Read()
```

Comment: acá esta documentado desde donde bajarlo y cómo configurarlo
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?2041

Comment: Estas seguro que solo actualizando la libreria se solucionaran? lo pregunto porque lo veo raro. No evaluaste si es un problema asociado al vinculo entre el cliente y el servidor donde alojas la db? Validaste sino es un problema de lockeo de las tablas, como trabajan las transacciones?

Comment: El problema es que el error que te arroja puede deberse a muchas cosas, principalmente a código mal formado, con que código te arroja ese error? "MySQLDriverCS Error: wrong query."